# Covering a div with a solid color or image Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently building a Chrome extension that aims to block out some of the content on Google Search. If a search result has a certain keyword my goal is to blacken it out and warn the user that a specific keyword is present in the search result.

I tried to add a background color to a div, but upon trying to make the div visible or hidden, I am unable to cover it with a message or blacken it out.

This is the best I've been able to achieve:
[image]

The first search term has the keyword I'm looking for, so a black background is added to it. But I want to hide the div and only display the black background with some warning message. Also, when the user clicks on the warning message, they should be able to view the blocked content.

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

I have already tried prepending another div to one that has the keyword and subsequently hiding the div with the keyword. This method did not work since I am using an event listener to check when all the DOM elements of the search are loaded, therefore using this method causes the div to be created multiple times and also causes the call stack to overflow.

Here is my manifest.json file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Replace Text",
    "version": "1.0", 

    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "googlestyles.css"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [ {
        "css":        ["googlestyles.css"],
        "js": [ "jquery-1.12.3.js", "content.js" ],
        "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    } ]
}
```

Here is my content.js file:

```
function replaceDivs() {
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("g");
    console.log(divs);
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
        var string = divs[i].innerText;
        var substr = "information"; //keyword to look for, in this case I picked a word that showed up on the first result.
        //            console.log(divs[i].getAttribute('id'));
        if (string.indexOf(substr) > -1) {
            divs[i].id = "num" + i.toString();
            $('#num' + i.toString()).addClass("black-bg");
            //$('#num' + i.toString()).prepend("<p>Test</p>") This is the part that went horribly wrong when I tried it.
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("test");
    document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', replaceDivs);
});
```

And finally, my custom css to add the black background:

```
.black-bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black !important;
}
```

All I need to to is to be able to fully cover the existing search result with an image or color and then fully reveal it when the image or color is clicked. But I've been struglging with this part for a while.

Any help on how to reolve this issue would be thoroughly appreciated.

Edit: Paradoxis' solution almost worked, but failed bacause the function is being called too many times:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using jquery's `$.append()`, check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zamrht7o/1/) I made really quickly

```
var width = $("#result").outerWidth();
var height = $("#result").outerHeight();

var $cover = $("<div class='coverme'></div>");
    $cover.width(width);
    $cover.height(height);
    $cover.css("top", $("#result").offset().top);
    $cover.css("left", $("#result").offset().left);

$("body").append($cover);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how will I be able to display an image or a background when I set the opacity to 0?

Comment: My goal is to hide the div and subsequently replace it with something else in the same place

Comment: You could try using `$.append` and place a div absolutely over the result

Comment: But when I use append, the thing that I'm trying to append gets appended many times since the function replaceDivs is called many times because of this line: document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', replaceDivs);

Comment: @athul777 I created a quick JSFiddle for you, maybe it helps

Comment: Thanks so much! I think I'll be able to resolve the issue now!

Comment: @athul777 No problem!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111203/discussion-between-athul777-and-paradoxis).

Comment: unfortunately, the solution did not work since the function is called too many times